# How to calculate the homology groups of the Möbius strip?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, mobius-band

How does one calculate the homology groups of the Möbius strip?

I'm thinking of two methods.

1. Use cellular homology. I tried to draw a delta-complex structure of the Möbius strip but I'm not sure if I'm right? I basically have a rectangle with opposite ends identified, so vertices (top-down) on the left are $a$ and $b$. On the right, they are $b$ and $a$. I know that there is an edge $e$ that joins from $b$ to $a$ and this is for both the left and right side of the rectangle. But this is not yet a delta complex structure, so I feel like I need to draw another edge across the rectangle from bottom left to top right, connecting $b$ to $b$. But how are these remaining 3 edges labelled? If I label the top and bottom edge, I think I'm creating another surface - the torus, RP2 or Klein bottle and so that's not the way to go. Does it mean this method is not possible?
2. Use $H_n(X^k,X)$ somehow, where $X^k$ is the $k$ skeleton of $X$. But I don't quite know how to proceed with this.

Any pointers in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I take it you don't want to use the fact that the circle and the Mobius strip are homotopy equivalent and homology is a homotopy invariant?

Comment: That is definitely an alternative to find the homology groups. But I'm having a question on calculating the homology groups of the Mobius strip involving it's delta-complex structure.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. It's definitely a good idea to practice techniques such as these on familiar spaces, even if you have other methods for calculating these invariants. I just wanted to make sure you weren't using a a hammer to screw two pieces of wood together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've attached a model for the Möbius band. The vertices are $a$ and $b$. The ones that eventually get glued together are given the same letter. The edges are labeled $A$, $B$ and $C$. There are two edges labelled $A$, and they have arrows. The must be glued so that the arrows agree, i.e. you need to give a half twist before you glue. The arrows on $B$ and $C$ are only there because we must orient simplices. Finally, $\alpha$ is the one face. I don't know how to put a clockwise arrow around it, so please add one.

[image]

To find the homology groups, we must look at the images and the kernels of the boundary maps. Consider the series of maps $0 \to F \to E \to V \to 0$, where $F$ stands for faces, $E$ for edges and $V$ for vertices. In between each is a boundary map.

- Consider $\partial : 0 \to F$. The image and the kernel are both $0$.
- Consider $\partial : F \to E$. We have $\partial \alpha = 2A+B+C$ and so the image is non-empty. There was only one face, so the image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. The only face had a non-zero image so the kernel is $0$.
- Consider $\partial : E \to V$. We have $\partial A = b-a$, $\partial B = a-b$ and $\partial C = a-b$. Up to an integer, the images are all $a-b$ and so the image is one dimensional: $\mathbb{Z}$. There were three edges, and the image was one dimensional, so the kernel must be two dimensional: $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
- Consider $\partial : V \to 0$. We have $\partial a = \partial b = 0$ and so the image is $0$. There are two vertices, and so the kernel must be $\mathbb{Z}^2.$

We can put all of this together. The group $H_2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by the quotient of the kernel of $F \to E$ by the image of $0 \to F$, i.e. $0/0 \cong 0$.  The group $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by the quotient of the kernel of $E \to V$ by the image of $F \to E$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The group $H_0(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by the quotient of the kernel of $V \to 0$ by the image of $E \to V$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Hence:

\begin{array}{ccc}
H_2(M,\mathbb{Z}) &\cong& \{0\} \\
H_1(M,\mathbb{Z}) &\cong& \mathbb{Z} \\
H_0(M,\mathbb{Z}) &\cong& \mathbb{Z}
\end{array}

Comment: I think for simplicial homology, faces must be triangles.

Comment: @HaikalYeo Are my results incorrect? I used a CW-complex, which yields exactly the same homology groups. Feel free to add extra edges and extra faces and spend longer making the calculations. You'll get exactly the same groups.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the step $\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$? This doesn't make sense to me. For example, if we view $\mathbb{Z}$ as embedded in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ via $a \mapsto (2a,0)$, then the quotient will be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @goblin The image of $\partial : F \to E$ is $\mathbb Z\langle 2A+B+C\rangle$ while the kernel of $\partial : E \to V$ is $\mathbb Z\langle A+B,A+C\rangle$. We want to find $\mathbb Z\langle A+B,A+C\rangle / \mathbb Z\langle 2A+B+C\rangle$. Notice that $(A+B)+(A+C)=2A+B+C$ and so $(A+B)+(A+C) \equiv 0$. $\mathbb Z\langle A+B,A+C\rangle$ has two generators, but they are linearly dependent, so there is only one linearly independent generator. Hence $\mathbb Z\langle A+B,A+C\rangle / \mathbb Z\langle 2A+B+C\rangle \cong \mathbb Z^1$

Comment: May I ask when can we compute the CW-complex pretending it is a simplicial complex like @Fly by Night , and when cannot?

Answer (score 10):

Take the usual paper strip that you would glue to make a Möbius strip.  If you want to get a simplicial complex, draw a line diagonally from the top corner on the left to the bottom corner on the right, so your paper strip is a union of two triangles.

Your strip now has two triangular faces, five 1-simplices (the four edges of the paper strip, together with the line you drew to divide it into two triangles), and 4 vertices.  But when you glue you identify the two edges at either end of the strip, so for the Möbius band there are two faces, four 1-simplices, and 2 vertices.

Now just write down the corresponding simplicial chain complex and compute away!

Answer (score 9):

A slick way of calculating the homology groups here is to notice that the Möbius strip is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Then you can apply Corollary 2.11 (Section 2.1) of Hatcher that:

The maps $\ f_{\ast} : H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(Y)$ induced by a homotopy equivalence $ \ f : X \rightarrow Y$ are isomorphisms for all $n$.

This should make the task much easier.